# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Tags: android, listview

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    Activity context;
    volatile String[] listW = new String[]{};
    volatile String[] listB = new String[]{};
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context,  String[] listW, String[] listB) {
        super();
        Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------------------------");

        this.context = context;
        this.listW= listW;
        this.listB= listB;


    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return listW.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text_view_listW;
        TextView text_view_listB;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text_view_listW = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_listW);
            holder.text_view_listB = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_listB);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "position="+position);
        Log.d(TAG, "listW.length="+listW.length);
        Log.d(TAG, "listB.length="+listB.length);
        Log.d(TAG, "listW="+listW[position]);
    if(!(listB[position].equals(""))&(listB.length!=position)&(listB.length==listW.length))   Log.d(TAG, "listB="+listB[position]);
```

Выкидывает ошибку на крайней строке

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Вот логкэт:

```
02-02 21:13:09.986 D/MyApp: position=0
02-02 21:13:09.986 D/MyApp: listW.length=1
02-02 21:13:09.986 D/MyApp: listB.length=0
02-02 21:13:09.986 D/MyApp: listW=D8
```

но чтобы она не выполнялась я поставил 3 исключения и ни одно не срабатывает. Что я мог упустить? Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Вот здесь `listB[position].equals("")`. Походу `listB` пустой, а вы пытаетесь извлечь первый элемент (который с индексом 0 ).

Comment: ;) похоже на правду.

Comment: Да эта ошибка ушла. Спасибо. Я настолько новичёк что допускаю такие очевидные ошибки.